# How to fix properties name while adding ArrayList<List<Integer>> to JSONArray and then to JSONObject

Tags: java, json, gson

i'm having a problem with  saving my results  to file. I have 2 Arraylists

```
ArrayList<List<Integer>>positions 
ArrayList<List<Integer>>positions2
```

with data format like this:

```
[[0,32],[39,19],[60,15],...]
```

I want to save this data to JSON file format like this:

```
"collocation": {
"first": [[0,32],[39,19],[60,15],...],
"second":  [[0,32],[39,19],[60,15],...]}
```

I tried following code to create first object

```
JSONArray JsonArray = new JSONArray(positions);
JSONObject Jsonobject = new JSONObject();
Jsonobject.put("first",JsonArray);
String jsooo = new Gson().toJson(Jsonobject);
```

And i end up with results:

```
{"map":{"first":{"myArrayList":[{"myArrayList":[0,32]},{"myArrayList":[39,19]},{"myArrayList":[60,15]}}
```

Why i'm getting "map" and "myArrayList" and how i can avoid/remove it to get what i want?

So, what i need to do to get format i need? This occurs only then i execute put(), but i dont know other ways to create structure like i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to directly store your `ArrayList<List<Integer>>` into a `JSONArray`. GSON is trying to store an array of `List<Integer>` objects and it don't know how to do that without creating `JSONObject` to hold it.

To solve this simply loop through the arrays, create JSONArray objects for each dimention and store them into an object.

```
    public static JSONObject saveValues(ArrayList<List<Integer>> pos1, ArrayList<List<Integer>> pos2)
        throws JSONException {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject collocation = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray first = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray second = new JSONArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < pos1.size(); i++) {
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < pos1.get(i).size(); j++) {
            arr.put(pos1.get(i).get(j));
        }
        first.put(arr);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < pos2.size(); i++) {
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < pos2.get(i).size(); j++) {
            arr.put(pos2.get(i).get(j));
        }
        second.put(arr);
    }

    collocation.put("first", first);
    collocation.put("second", second);
    obj.put("collocation", collocation);

    return obj;
}
```

The above returns a `JSONObject` that looks like this:

```
{"collocation":{"first":[[10,20],[3,6]],"second":[[80,76],[12,65]]}}
```